# Enable CORS, but deny direct access via browser

Tags: c#, .net

I want to enable Cross-origin-access, but only from `https://example.com`. However, I'd also like to deny all direct access that does not come from this domain as well.

With the following code I am able to allow CORS from that domain, but I am still able to just navigate to the API URL in my browser and get the `Secret code` response.

```
[EnableCors(origins: "https://example.com", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // GET: api/Values
    public string Get()
    {
        return "Secret code";
    }
}
```

Comment: You could enforce a secret header

Comment: @hardkoded "a secret header" - lol

Comment: OP: CORS is a browser mechanism applied to XHR requests from javascript. Hosting your page on the same host as your origin, or navigating directly to an endpoint will not engage CORS. It's not intended to control access to your API - it's meant to allow browsers to determine if a cross-origin request is allowed (to prevent XSS attacks).

Comment: @PWL Are you trying to do so without making use of authorization/certification?

Comment: You could accept only `Content-Type = application/json`.

Comment: are you using iis ?

Comment: @Jared Yes, the "secret code" will be a generated ticket that will be used to access a third party page. The reason I cannot attach some kind of "key" is that the request is done with Javascript, which means the key would be fully visible to the users.

Comment: @PWL You'll either need authentication+cookie or authentication+access token.

Comment: @John has hit the nail on the head, you'll need to authenticate via these methods if you cannot use certification via keys to restrict access.

Comment: So there's no way of knowing that the request came from a Javascript code on a certain website (check for IP/domain)?

Comment: @PWL No, not with certainty. You can check the referrer to get the domain, but this is very easily spoofed. The IP will just be the one assigned to the client by their ISP - that could be pretty much anything.